# Mat ForEachAsByte has a different pixelcount after every run

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a Mat 8 bits grayscale image, where I'm trying to loop through using the ForEachAsInt16() function.

The Mat image is configured as the following:

```
{Mat [ 642*190*CV_8UC1, IsContinuous=False, IsSubmatrix=True, Ptr=0x75c8cf8, Data=0xcce4481 ]}
```

This Mat is a submatrix from a larger image of `720*1280*CV_8UC1`

When I loop through this Mat and try to count the pixels, the code returns a different number of pixels everytime. Does anyone know why this is happening?

The code to execute this is as follows:

```
var ridgeImageRoi = new Mat(ridgeImage, new Rect(roi.MinPoint.X, roi.MinPoint.Y, roi.MaxPoint.X - roi.MinPoint.X, roi.MaxPoint.Y - roi.MinPoint.Y));
unsafe
{
    int pixelcounter = 0;
    ridgeImageRoi.ForEachAsByte((byte* pixel, int* position) =>
    {
        pixelcounter++;
    });
    Console.WriteLine(pixelcounter);
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be 642*190 = 121980

But instead I'm getting the following outputs I run this:

```
78791
69079
72792
71272
79689
```

This output is different everytime, but always around the 70000.

Comment: Is ForEachAsByte a method that uses multithreading so that iterations run or might run in parallel?

Comment: If that is the case try a `Interlocked.Increment(pixelcounter)` instead of a simple ++.

Comment: That indeed seems to fix the problem, it's a multitreading issue. After using interlocked the pixelcounter is exactly what I expected it to be